# apache returning "The connection was reset"

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, nginx, connection

One of my dedicated servers had some network issue today and the data center has to replace some router. Since then the sites on that server returns "The connection was reset" error most of the time.

I tried installing nginx and it opens better, but it still shows the error sometimes.

Everything in the config seems normal, what could be causing this error?

**UPDATE:**

Just noticed that in whm > apache status there are always only 1 requests currently being processed, 8 idle workers. I know for sure the server received thousands of requests per minute. What could be limiting this to such a low number?

Comment: Post your apache confs, specifically the ones surrounding, Min/MaxServers, ServerLimit, MaxClients, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be running both apache2 and nginx, I imagine that they would both compete for port 80. Hence you would have to provide more details of your setup.

To show which process has port 80;

```
netstat -lntp
```

see which services are running;

```
ps -ef | egrep "(httpd|nginx)"
```

show which server is listening locally;

```
 $ perl -MLWP::Simple -e 'print [LWP::Simple::head("http://127.0.0.1")]->[-1]';
 Apache
```

show apache configuration;

```
 # apachectl -S
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, file is empty. But check the updated question, any idea about that workers limit?

Comment: If nginx or apache is already running when you start the other they cannot bind to port 80 so they fail start (address already in use)

Comment: why the downvote?